# Can't create_stack with CloudFormation with aws cli but can in the portal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a working cloudFormation yaml template. I know its working because when I go to the aws portal and create a stack by clicking-away the stack gets created.

However, when I try to use the cloudformation on the command line the same yaml errors out.

I'm at loss to what's causing this issue. Does anyone know what may be causing the failure?

Here is the command I am calling

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name ${stack_name} --template-body file://template.yaml --region ${region}
```

where region is the same region I am in the aws portal. And here is the `template.yaml`

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: EC2 example instance
Resources:
  TestEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-01ec0fa63b2042232
      InstanceType: t3.medium
      SubnetId: subnet-*********
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          echo "Running apt install -y git nfs-common binutils jq"
          apt-get install -y git nfs-common binutils jq
```

when I run the command I see the stack starting to be created on the portal with the following events

```
ec2-boilerplate ROLLBACK_COMPLETE   -
TestEC2Instance DELETE_COMPLETE -
TestEC2Instance DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  -
ec2-boilerplate ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS    The following resource(s) failed to create: [TestEC2Instance]. Rollback requested by user.
TestEC2Instance CREATE_FAILED   Instance i-0bdd3e7ee34edf1ef failed to stabilize. Current state: shutting-down. Reason: Client.InternalError: Client error on launch
TestEC2Instance CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  Resource creation Initiated
TestEC2Instance CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  -
ec2-boilerplate CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  User Initiated
```

Is it something about my template.yaml? about my command line call? some environment variable?

Comment: Do you have any logs of the EC2 that failed to stabilize?

Comment: how can I access the logs of the EC2 instance? it shows as terminated in my ec2 dashboard. When I try the system-logs it shows empty

Comment: What OS are you using? What is `ami-01ec0fa63b2042232`?

Comment: Just guessing, but is there a permission difference between the user you used for login/creation from console and the user used by the aws CLI for command-line? Say, permission to the AMI or KMS, which may be used.

Comment: @RegisterSole this may be the case, how can I check the different permission configuratins for each case?

Comment: All permissions are defined in IAM. If you are logging in using username/password, typically you can find your username in IAM users, then find the group you belong to in IAM groups. The permissions are in the policies attached to the group. For the CLI, it depends. If it is run from EC2, it may be the IAM role attached to it. Else, it should be a security credential, usually in `<home>/.aws/credentials`. Then you need to find out this security credential belongs to which IAM user. If you didn't set this up, then whoever set it up, such as your admin, will know.

Comment: Can you compare the stack template created by cloudformation (When using the UI) vs template.yaml you have provided? What is different?

Comment: @RaghavSharma as mentioned in the question they are exactly the same document. So nothing is different

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the length of time the instance is taking to create, but your 'userdata' script seems simple enough that it is hard to imagine that being the case. The AWS documentation states that this error relates to [the resource creation time exceeding the CloudFormation timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-resource-did-not-stabilize):

> A resource didn't respond because the operation exceeded the AWS
> CloudFormation timeout period or an AWS service was interrupted. For
> service interruptions, check that the relevant AWS service is running,
> and then retry the stack operation.

One quick thing I would check is that the [`-e` option to bash](https://serverfault.com/questions/391255/what-does-passing-the-xe-parameters-to-bin-bash-do) in your userdata script isn't causing it to fail in some way that hinders instance creation.

Another possible solution, per the AWS recommendation, is to ensure that your CloudFormation stack is [provided a service role when it is created](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-servicerole.html). This will allow it to create infrastructure beyond the timeout imposed when using the creating user's IAM permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your possible solutions, but since this all works in the portal but not on the cli, I think the options of taking too much time (in the portal its very fast), the error in bash, in the portal there is no error, etc. don't apply

Comment: @gota While I agree, I'm curious as to what happens if you try to use a service role when running from the CLI. There *shouldn't* be a difference, but in my experience the tooling in which you run things often carries invisible context that can only be discovered by observation.